# How to close the java Program?

Tags: java, arrays

Unable to close the program,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArrayExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customer.txt"));
                while (reader != null) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        String[] lineSplitted = line.split(",");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                            System.out.println("Element at index " + i +": " + lineSplitted[i]);
                        }
                        line = null;
                        System.out.println(lineSplitted[0]);
                        System.out.println(lineSplitted[1]);
                        System.out.println(lineSplitted[2]);
                    } 
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by closing ?

Comment: After running the code cursor enter into the last line and still looking for something.

Comment: Use if(line !=null) instead if  while (line != null)

Comment: and what lies in "Customer.txt" file ?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake in

```
while (reader != null)
```

Cause it is a endless loop

I don't know why you write this line of code, but i think it's not what you want and need:)

Oh, and try to rewrite your code with try-with-resources like:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("Customer.txt");
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
    // your code logic            
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IOException while reading file");
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if `reader != null` were false, to break the loop, `reader.close()` would then fail with a `NullPointerException`.